# core data unable to fetch data due to error: unable to format the parse string nspredicate

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

while watching youtube tutorial on core data(    https://youtu.be/mEAav7dM4hk?t=1581) * am succefully able to save data, but when i try to fetch the data upon "searchperson" button press it throws up error:

```
 I HAVE GOT TWO TEXT FIELDS :firstname and lastname

 I HAVE GOT THREE BUTTONS :addperson, sarchperson and deleteperson

 I HAVE GOT ONE DISPLAY LABEL TO TELL WHETER DATA(person) ADDED OR NOT

   error:
    CoreDataTutorialz2[1601:907] *** Terminating app due to 
   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
  'Unable to parse the format string "firstname like %@, 
 lastname like %@"'
```

-(IBAction)searchperson:(id)sender

```
 {

 NSEntityDescription *entitydesc=[NSEntityDescription   entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

[request setEntity:entitydesc];

NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname  like %@, lastname like  %@",self.firstnametextfield.text,self.lastnametextfield.text];

[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;

NSArray *matchingData=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSLog(@"error:%@",error);

if(matchingData.count <=0)
{
    self.displaylabel.text=@"no person found";
}
else
{
    NSString *first_name;
    NSString *last_name;

    for(NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData )
    {
        first_name=[obj valueForKey:@"firstname"];
        last_name=[obj valueForKey:@"lastname"];
    }

   self.displaylabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:
   @"firstname=%@, lastname=%@",first_name,last_name];


}
  https://youtu.be/mEAav7dM4hk?t=1581

 CAN ANYONE HELP ME OUT WHATS WRONG HERE. THANKS IN ADVANCE!
```

Comment: CAN ANYONE HELP ME OUT WHATS WRONG HERE. THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: `firstname  like %@ AND lastname like  %@` or `firstname like %@ OR lastname like  %@` according to what you want.

Comment: I HAVE GOT TWO TEXT FIELDS :firstname and lastname
  I HAVE GOT THREE BUTTONS :addperson, sarchperson and deleteperson
  I HAVE GOT ONE DISPLAY LABEL TO TELL WHETER DATA(person) ADDED OR NOT

Comment: Stop yelling (using uppercase). The solution I gave you should fix the predicate error.

Comment: @Larme sorry to use upper case, thanks for you help, but the problem still persists after using AND the error now is : Unable to parse the format string "firstname like %@, AND lastname like %@"'

Comment: I did't put a comma before AND, I removed it.

Comment: @Larme thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found after going through `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468095/nspredicate-with-core-data?rq=1`

NSPredicate  *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname   CONTAINS %@ AND lastname CONTAINS %@",self.firstnametextfield.text,self.lastnametextfield.text ];